# Using Cordova plugin with IONIC not ionic-native

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I am trying to use local notifications cordova plugin from [here](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications).

I don't want to use the ionic-native solution from [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/) because it does not implement all features I need.

I have installed the cordova plugin like so
`cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications`

Then I try to use after platform.ready like so..

```
   this.plt.ready().then(()=> {
         (<any>window).plugins.notification.local.schedule({
         id: 1,
         title: "Fitness App",
         text: "Timer done",
         priority: 1,
         at: Date.now()
       });
   });
```

I have tested this on a real device and in the browser (although I know it won't work in the browser). In the browser it says that notification is not defined.

My question is how can I properly import the plugin to use with ionic.

Comment: You have not asked a question yet, though. So it works on device but you don't want the error in the browser?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Using the following code allowed me to use the cordova plugin with IONIC. Without having to use the ionic-native solution.

```
declare var cordova;

(<any>cordova).plugins.notification.local.schedule({
```